# Remove or Disabled style sheet from a page linked though link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

I am trying to disable two css links from my page which are linked using Link tag.

```
 <div class="ExportedContent"> 
  <link href="//thisismysite/common14/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//thisismysite/common14/stylesheet_2014.css" type="text/css"> 
 </div>
```

I have following code to remove this link which is not working

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('link[href="https://grants.nih.gov/common14/css/bootstrap.min.css"]').remove();
$('link[href="https://grants.nih.gov/common14/stylesheet_2014.css"]').remove();
});
</script>
```

So far this is not working any ideas

Comment: `link[src`?, you mean `href`

Comment: yeah i corrected it now but still doesn't work

Comment: `html` and `js` appear to have different `href` attribute values ?

Answer (score 1):

`link` elements at `html` and selector at `js` appear to have different `href` attribute values ?

Try using attribute ends with selector , `.removeAttr()`

```
$("link[href$='bootstrap.min.css'], link[href$='stylesheet_2014.css']")
.removeAttr("href")
```

Comment: i get this error jquery.js:1458Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: link[href$=bootstrap.min.css] for this

Comment: @user388969 Ah, `.` character needs to be escaped with "\\", or value of attribute quoted; try updated post

Answer (score 0):

Your links starts with `//domain`
and your selector starts with `https://domain`
That is a non match

What you could do is using [[name$=”value”]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector that match something that ends with a given string. This comparison is case sensitive.

Another thing you could work with instead of removing the link tag is `document.styleSheets`
And may i say that it looks odd that the link tags are inside a div tag...

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true
```